# Fill Json with missed Data

Tags: json, database

I have a json and in my example values for years 1996 to 2012 were left out. Is there any way to insert the missing values (years)? If yes, how? Finally, the json should be completely filled in (1988 to 2021) and insert the value "0" for the years where the year is missing.

Kind Regards and thank you

```json
{
  "data": {
    "ArrayValue": [
      0.0030350000000000004,
      0.003661,
      0.0080348532,
      0.0053554275,
      0.004284,
      0.008569710000000001,
      0.008569710000000001,
      0.007498282499999999,
      0.189286,
      0.42142999999999997,
      0.461429,
      0.5075000000000001,
      0.5575,
      0.615,
      0.705,
      0.76,
      0.8075,
      0.865,
      0.89
    ],
    "ArrayYears": [
      "1988",
      "1989",
      "1990",
      "1991",
      "1992",
      "1993",
      "1994",
      "1995",
      "2012",
      "2013",
      "2014",
      "2015",
      "2016",
      "2017",
      "2018",
      "2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "TTM"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Language tag? What have you tried?

Comment: Oh sorry! We use React.

Answer (score 0):

2012 *is* there. Filling in 1996 - 2011:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('input.json');
let obj = JSON.parse(rawdata);

const len = 16;
const insertPos = 8;
const totSize = 35;

const tempArrData = new Array(len).fill(0);

const tempArrYears = new Array(len);
let i = 0;
for (let y = 1996; y < 2012; y += 1) {
  tempArrYears[i] = y + '';
  i += 1;
}

const arrV = obj.data.ArrayValue;
arrV.splice(insertPos, 0, ...tempArrData);

const arrY = obj.data.ArrayYears;
arrY.splice(insertPos, 0, ...tempArrYears);

for (let i = 0; i < totSize; i += 1) {
  console.log(`${obj.data.ArrayYears[i]} , ${obj.data.ArrayValue[i]}`);
}
```

Output:

```
1988 , 0.0030350000000000004
1989 , 0.003661
1990 , 0.0080348532
1991 , 0.0053554275
1992 , 0.004284
1993 , 0.008569710000000001
1994 , 0.008569710000000001
1995 , 0.007498282499999999
1996 , 0
1997 , 0
1998 , 0
1999 , 0
2000 , 0
2001 , 0
2002 , 0
2003 , 0
2004 , 0
2005 , 0
2006 , 0
2007 , 0
2008 , 0
2009 , 0
2010 , 0
2011 , 0
2012 , 0.189286
2013 , 0.42142999999999997
2014 , 0.461429
2015 , 0.5075000000000001
2016 , 0.5575
2017 , 0.615
2018 , 0.705
2019 , 0.76
2020 , 0.8075
2021 , 0.865
TTM , 0.89
```